# How To Override Datalist To Be Rendered Into Divs Instead Of Table?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to render datalist to divs instead of table and the repeat columns will fixed by float style on div.

So any one knows an override render method to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this solution but I posted it to help others;

Some users suggest to use repeater and that is right, but for that case to replace `div` instead of `table` in `datalist`

```
RepeatLayout=RepeatLayout.Flow
```

This will make it `span` with `br`.
But using `Horizontal` for `RepeatDirection` wil remove `br` but still items rendered with `span`.

```
RepeatDirection=RepeatDirection.Horizontal
```

This statement will remove `br` but still items rendered with `span`.

So override `RenderContents` to create your own `divs` outside `span` and remove `br` if you do not want to use `Horizontal RepeatDirection`, as follow:

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter w)
{
    writer.WriteBeginTag("div");
    writer.WriteAttribute("id", this.ClientID);
    writer.WriteAttribute("class", cssClass);
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    foreach (DataListItem li in this.Items)
    {
        writer.WriteBeginTag("div");
        writer.WriteAttribute("id", li.ClientID);
        writer.WriteAttribute("class", li.CssClass);
        writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
        li.CssClass = null; // clear css not to added in span
        li.RenderControl(w);
        writer.WriteEndTag("div");
    }
    writer.WriteEndTag("div");

}
```

My Regards

Comment: i will but system here must wait for 2 days :)

Comment: I get "no suitable method found to override" if I inherit from System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater

Answer (score 2):

Use the `<asp:Repeater>` control instead of the `<asp:DataList>` control.
Within the `<ItemTemplate>` of the `<asp:Repeater>` you can use the `<div>` tags to control the layout, as the repeater does not render any html of its own apart from what you give it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i keep in mind this answer, but i have a custom control datalist with paging and some other options will make difficult to change it :)

Comment: The paging isnt really that difficult to implement with a repeater. You can use a PagedDataSource to control the data, and then render the pagination yourself. I have never not been able to do anything with the repeater control that other controls can do.

Comment: the problem is that control is placed in many pages in my project 5 years, and customized to do every thing, but your opinion is right, let me try and tell you, :) Thanks again

Comment: look at this: RepeatDirection=RepeatDirection.Horizontal and RepeatLayout=RepeatLayout.Flow render it with span and no br, i tried to override TagKey to Div but span not changed, any ideas to change span into div?

Comment: Thanks for your try, and i found a solution for that case behind that using repeater is good one.

Answer (score 1):

I always set the DataList to Flow layout like:

```
RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="my_repeater_cssclass"
```

The problem here is that as mentioned above .NET still gives you a **br** tag to play with.

My solution is just set the br tag that the DataList generates to display:none through a CSS class applied to the DataList itself.

```
.my_repeater_cssclass br
{
    display : none;   
}
```

Then, if, for some reason you have br tags you do want to show, just give your br tag a css class and make it do what you want...like for my actual example I ended up using it to clear a float after every row:

```
.my_repeater_cssclass br.clear
{
    display : block;
    clear : both;
}
```

If you have **a lot** of br tags to deal with then this may not be your solution.  But I find it a nice simple fix.