# Display images retrieved from database as list with CSS style

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, image, grid

I'm a newbie to ASP.NET and I'm having trouble finding a solution to display images retrieved from database as list with CSS style. There are a couple of solutions I've found, like using DataList, DataGrid, Repeater, etc. but they all end up displaying images in table cells, and the spacing is dynamic with the number of images fetched. So I'm wondering whether there is any way to display images in ASP.NET image control along with CSS style (like how you can do with PHP, I know how weird that sounds). Or is there anyway to display them neatly in fixed columns? I'm a dummy here so please be kind to me and help me. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You can write your own web custom cotrol/user control and render images using styles/CSS like the way in PHP or others. All you have to do is to override Render event. You cal also do using literal control. And another choice is you add item template to your datagrid and display your images. Finally what I would suggest is first work with HTML CSS which will list your some images, once you are sure with that then implement in one of the ways. Finally you have to render HTML tags that you have created in your sample HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using WebForms and want to stick with the .net controls, have a look at [ListView](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed tutorial, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that.

You can make a simple `foreach` loop that you simple render your images and show the results. No need to use other controls. I place the images inside `li` because you can make them with simple css style to render as table.

```
List<string> lMyImages = new List<string>();
StringBuilder sRenderOnMe = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var OneImg in lMyImages)
   sRenderOnMe.AppendFormat("<li><img src=\"{0}\"></li>", OneImg);

OneLiteral.Text = sRenderOnMe.ToString():
```

You can also use an `asp:Repeater`, that you can render inside it what ever you like. how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="Repeater1">
    <itemtemplate>
      <li><img src="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImgSrc") %>"></li>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

You can overwrite the DataList and render it as you like with divs, how : [How To Override Datalist To Be Rendered Into Divs Instead Of Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647304/how-to-override-datalist-to-be-rendered-into-divs-instead-of-table)

Css: Here is the way that using the `<li`> you can render the images shown as dynamic table: http://mirificampress.com/permalink/the_amazing_li

Answer (score 0):

Repeater won't create any table unless use like this, and you can stylize with css may it will help you.

```
<ul>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptr" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="lnk" runat="server">/asp:LinkButton>|
                </ContentTemplate>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```